# How to Calculate Mean Cross Entropy for Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, mean-square-error, machine-precision

I have 2 arrays of size N.

> X= array of predicted probabilities
>
> Y= observed probabilities

This can be interpreted as

> X[i] = the predicted probability of the event occurring on trial i.Values are floats from 0-1
>
> Y[i] = the observed probability of the event occurring on trial i. Values are floats from 0-1

Im using a machine learning model and run it on all N trials in order to produce X. I would like to measure how accurate the model's prediction (X) was to the observed probability (Y).

Im currently using Mean Squared Error to measure accuracy but I think [Mean Cross Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) is a better metric to use. Im not sure how(or if its possible) to Calculate MXE between X & Y?

Answer (score 2):

First, this question would be better suited for "Cross Validated" group - statisticians are there.
However, 
$$
CE(X,Y) = -\frac{\sum_j^M{\sum_i^N{X_i \log{Y_i}}}}{M}
$$
Where $X_i$ - expected probabilities of events, $Y_i$ - observed.
$N$ - set size, $M$ - batch size, so we averaging over batch.

Comment: How does the above work? Would I be aiming to maximize or minimize CE(X,Y)? The Y's are not all 1 and I think the above makes that assumption? I do plan on doing cross validation but I still need a metric to know the accuracy.

Comment: I have corrected calculation to get average over batch. Entropy has to be minimized - think as perfect order - it shall $\to$ zero, i.e. $X_i = 1, Y_i = 1$ in perfect match case.

Comment: I still do not follow. Lets say for example The observed probabilities are Y = [0.6, 0.8, 0.1] and the predicted values X = [0.6, 0.8, 0.1]. In this case we have a perfect match but CE != 0.

Comment: There is a difference between correlation and CE correlation. If sequences are identical - their correlation is highest. Entropy is a different - it is measure of disorder. Events with probabilities < 1 will always have non-zero entropy. Moreover, probabilities has to present densities, i.e. sum to 1. CE is a measure of the informational entropy of one sequence given known distribution of another.